# SQL Server backup failing with Error 64

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

I'm useing SQL Server backup to an unc path.  I'm getting the following error on a fairly regular basis now:

```
BackupDiskFile::RequestDurableMedia:  failure on backup device 'the unc path\filename here' Operating system error 64(The specified network name is no longer available.).
```

Is there any way to get this consistent?  I have asked the network group and they say there is no network issue here.  I saw 1 writeup saying to set the SQL Server memory to a fixed amount (there is 32 gb on the server, and this is a SharePoint database).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is notorious for being delicate with network shares (this is supposedly supposed to improved with SQL Server 2012).  If there is any loss of transmition or minimal timeout then SQL Server will abort the backup.

Your best bet is to backup to a local disk and then transfer the backup files to the network share outside of SQL Server.  You can automate that as well, so you don't have to do these manual steps.

Comment: I have tried that and when I copy the file it goes for almost 1 hour then get an error message saying that a process has the file locked.

Comment: @GaryMazzone what process has a lock on the file??  I'm guessing you're waiting until after SQL Server has finished the backup?  If so, you may have another process that has a handle on it.  Run Process Monitor and see what has a handle on the file to further troubleshoot this.